# WebView problem - on click open new Activity

Tags: android

I have image ( building cross layout and need to put that on background, always same dimensions ) and I have list of air conditioners with x_coord and y_coord on image ( that list is changeable and I need dynamically to add air conditioners on layout). I need to enabled zoom layout with air conditioners on and on click on some air conditioner to open new activity. I thought to use WebView and create page ( background to be layout, and every air conditioner be  and to on click to do something - javascrit), but how to implement that on click I change to new activity from WebView ( I know JavScript, but how to connect that with Android ) ? Any suggestion or advice ? Is possible at any way that from onclick javascript somehow opet new activity in android app ?

Comment: need more elaboration and specifically

Answer (score 0):

You set in the html special links like air://etc, and then register your activity to handle those special URIs. That information should get you going.